# How to resolve Network Failure net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

[image]I am doing a Get request to AWS. Fetching the list of bucket through browser(Javascript). I'm getting the below error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.
>   When I leave region blank, I get following errors.
>   please see the screen shot above for errors i m getting.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.2.41.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="status"></div>
        <ul id="objects"></ul>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'key', secretAccessKey: 'GwP/secretkey/XkoAd89kGs'});
        // Configure your region
        AWS.config.region = 'US Standard';

        var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'rentonclick'}});
    bucket.listObjects(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error',err);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' items from S3';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('objects').innerHTML +=
                    '<li>' + data.Contents[i].Key + '</li>';
            }
        }
    });

    </script>

</html>
```

I am also sharing the plunker -
https://plnkr.co/edit/uw9j9tpfvJ4cRqjbF7nC?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Amazon AWS region is invalid.

Please look for your region in your Amazon AWS dashboard. It should look like this.

`AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';`

Goodluck.

Comment: Hi, as per my understanding the region should be the region  set for bucket.
Region for my bucket is same which I have mentioned.
So I think this might not be the reason.

Comment: Hi, i've tried it myself and s3 does not use a region. So in that case i would leave the region empty.(`AWS.config.region = '';`) With the region empty i get the following URL: https://rentonclick.s3.amazonaws.com/ Is this your bucket?

Comment: Yes,this is my bucket.But in AWS docs they have mentioned to use region for any get request.What does it mean to leave region blank? Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

We need configure CORS like this - This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

when i use vue axio, eg:

```
var config = {
   site: 'http://192.168.0.71:9000/doapi/',
}
export const API_ROOT = 'http://'.concat( config.site)
did you find something wrong: API_ROOT = 'http://'+ 'http://192.168.0.71:9000/doapi/';
```

'http://' has declared twice. delete it. ok